# How do I use Node.js modules?

Tags: javascript, node.js, module, npm, linode

I recently installed *Node.js* on a fresh Linode box, and I think I'm in a weird situation where I can't use `require()` to load any third party modules.

I've installed `npm` and have successfully installed modules via `npm`, but whenever I try to `require` one of the modules (or just some of my own code in the same directory), *Node.js* `throws` an `error` saying it can't find the module.

Any thoughts as to why this might be happening?

Here's an example error message:

> ```
> root@li200-141:/home/mike# npm install sequelize
> npm ERR! sudon't!
> npm ERR! sudon't! Running npm as root is not recommended!
> npm ERR! sudon't! Seriously, don't do this!
> npm ERR! sudon't!
> npm info it worked if it ends with ok
> npm info version 0.2.2
> npm info fetch http://registry.npmjs.org/sequelize/-/sequelize@0.4.2.tgz
> npm info install sequelize@0.4.2
> npm info activate sequelize@0.4.2
> npm info build Success: sequelize@0.4.2
> npm ok
>
> root@li200-141:/home/mike# node
> > var n = require('sequelize').Sequelize
> Error: No such native module sequelize
>     at requireNative (node.js:83:32)
>     at cwdRequire (repl:27:10)
>     at [object Context]:1:9
>     at Interface.<anonymous> (repl:96:19)
>     at Interface.emit (events:27:15)
>     at Interface._ttyWrite (readline:295:12)
>     at Interface.write (readline:132:30)
>     at Stream.<anonymous> (repl:77:9)
>     at Stream.emit (events:27:15)
>     at IOWatcher.callback (net:489:16)
> ```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Apparently, there is a bug in node v0.2.2 that prevents require from working properly from the REPL.

Try putting your code in a .js file instead.  That worked for me.

Comment: Can confirm. You can't `require` a module from the command line in the latest version of Node.JS. Sad but true.